# JavaScript setInterval runs only once

Tags: javascript, image, setinterval

```
function smoothTransition(o,n)
{
    o.style.opacity = 0;
    o.src = n;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (o.style.opacity == 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        o.style.opacity += 0.01;
    }, 10);
}
```

here o is the object(which is an img in this case), and n is the name of the new image that will be replacing the current one. but when I run this code it only runs once and gives 0.01 opacity to the new image and then stops. What might be causing this?

Comment: Can you add a more complete example that we can look at and test on jsfiddle.net or similar service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style.opacity` is a string, not a number.  When you do `o.style.opacity += 0.1` the result is actually `'00.1'`, which is valid, but in the next iteration it becomes `00.10.1`, which is not, so the opacity is reset to `0`.

This is solved pretty easily by casting `style.opacity` to a number when you do the addition.

http://jsfiddle.net/TZ9Vd/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going nuts over this.